# Strange behaviour when trying to detect spaces and tabs in grammar

Tags: grammar, xtext

I am having trouble detecting spaces and tabs in my grammar. My spaces and tabs are *not* hidden in my grammar.

I have the grammar:

```
Model: defs+=Def*;

Def:
    'actor' WS ID NEWLINE
;
```

And a terminal:

```
terminal WS : (' '|'\t')+;
```

But I can't seem to get the whitespaces to be noticed correctly. I can input any combinations of spaces and tabs between 'actor' and the ID, as long as there is more than one space. If I input only one space between them, I get problems. For example, this works:

```
Actor                          Bob
```

But when I try with only a single space:

```
Actor Bob
```

I get errors like this:

```
- extraneous input 'Bob' expecting RULE_NEWLINE
- mismatched input ' ' expecting RULE_WS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have a single white-space somewhere in your grammar used as a keyword. You have to remove that one.